# Hi. Is there a way to write this code more briefly and avoid repeating ((if)) ? I am beginner

Tags: python

[C:\Users\lenovo\Pictures\1400-10-04 20_12_32-untitled1 – practice.py PyCharm.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ff1Vh.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Add your code as formatted text. It's inconvenient to work with your screenshot, no chance to copy your code.

Comment: You could sort the list to get the rank of every element. Recommended [reading](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html)

Comment: Also it would help to know what exactly you're trying to do. For example do you want to check against for arbitrary lists, or will it always be this exact list?

Answer (score 1):

you can improve your code adding an initial sorting and utilizing the index function.
code:

```
your_physics_point = int(input('please insert your point: '))

#solve:
#first check
if your_physics_point not in class_points :
    print('your inserted point is NOT found!')
else:
    #sort the list decreasing
    class_points.sort(reverse=True)
    #create a dict
    scale = {1: "first", 2: "second", 3:"thrid", 4:'fourth', 5:'fifth'}
    #find the index
    ind = class_points.index(your_physics_point)
    #printing
    print('you are ' + scale[ind+1] + '!')
```